# cdn.sstatic.net not reachable via IPv6 http

Tags: bug, cdn, ipv6

```
http://cdn.sstatic.net/askubuntu/all.css 
http://[2400:cb00:2048:1::be5d:f53a]/askubuntu/all.css
```

is not reachable via IPv6. 
When trying to access any site, cdn.sstatic.net is not reachable via IPv6 http and therefore does not load.

If IPv6 is disabled, all sites work just fine.

ICMP/Ping works just fine, but http traffic times out.

```
Tracing route to 2400:cb00:2048:1::be5d:f53a over a maximum of 30 hops 
1 1 ms 1 ms 1 ms vlan10.dhk10.core-backbone.com [2a01:4a0:1337::1]
2 1 ms <1 ms <1 ms xae0-4023.nbg20.core-backbone.com [2a01:4a0:0:4023::2]
3 3 ms 4 ms 4 ms xae0-2002.fra20.core-backbone.com [2a01:4a0:0:2002::4]
4 3 ms 3 ms 3 ms ae51-3356.edge7.Frankfurt1.Level3.net [2001:1900:5:2:2::75]
5 3 ms 3 ms 3 ms vl-60.edge4.Frankfurt1.Level3.net [2001:1900:104:5::9]
6 3 ms 3 ms 11 ms Telia-level3-10G.Frankfurt.Level3.net [2001:1900:5:3::24e]
7 88 ms 88 ms 88 ms prs-b8-v6.telia.net [2001:2000:3018:2a::1]
8 98 ms 97 ms 97 ms cloudflare-ic-154355-prs-b8.c.telia.net  [2001:2000:3080:567::2]
9 89 ms 89 ms 89 ms 2400:cb00:2048:1::be5d:f53a 
Trace complete.
```